# What can I do to re-install VBSCRIPT for Windows 7? 

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I've had a problem with VBSCRIPT preventing me from updating the McAfee I paid for. It now is preventing me from updating my Sprint cell connection. In addition, since the Sprint update failed, I can not re-install the original. Because "VBSCRIPT file (s) are missing".

Can I download a full load of VBSCRIPT that will work? Can it be re-installed? Or do I need to reload the wonderful OS?

Comment: What error message are you seeing exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Either the DLL is missing or there are registry issues or both.

To check if it's missing and replace it, use the **sfc** command at the command prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```

If that doesn't fix it, check [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-2738-could-not-access-vbscript-run-time-for/1a4499ae-8bc1-4534-9c6f-4d399ac70d9a) which details a Microsoft fix for potential registry problems.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, VBSCIPT is a scripting language. There is no installer for it as it is simply included with Windows.

If you are receiving a VBSCRIPT.DLL file is missing error, check your recycle bin to see if you mistakenly deleted it and restore it from there.

You can also go to Windows Update and apply any updates that are listed there or re-apply the most recent service pack followed by any missing Windows Updates. In this case, VBSCRIPT.DLL could be a part of the Windows Update/Service Pack and get "fixed" as a part of the updating process.

Answer (score -2):

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> to open Task Manager and check if you have any `wscript.exe` running. If so terminate it.

VBScript is a programming language, the extension for the files is `.vbs` and runs using the `wscript.exe` (almost like JAVA)

Also go to Start -> Run and type: `msconfig`  press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and go to the Startup tab and see whats loading there. Check under the command column if there is anyone linking to a `.vbs` file and deactivate it.

Optimally you should only have you antivirus and sometimes control panel for audio stuff VIA, REALTEK, something along that.